# Docker running script in entrypoint

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

In Dockerfile I have defined an **entrypoint**:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

In the `docker-entrypoint.sh`, I want to create a file (`file.json`) from the `template.json`, which is nothing but replaces some environment variables with actual values.

```
#! /bin/bash

eval "echo \"$(<template.json)\"" > file.json; npm start
```

Now, after getting in the container, I see `file.json` is empty. But if I execute the exact same command in the bash prompt inside the container, it works, and I see the required contents in `file.json`.

Why is this behaviour ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with your interpreter: `sh` 
Try exec form:  `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: Since this was the solution, could you please convert this from a comment into an answer?

Comment: I beg your pardon.I am new here so I really do not understand what are you suggesting.  This was the answer from me, not a comment. Something more I need to do ?

Comment: You wrote a comment as the answer. The comment ended up solving it. If you could rephrase the answer as a declaratory solution instead of an interrogative comment, then it could not be flagged as "not an answer", which it is susceptible to at the moment. I would suggest instead of speculating and asking in the answer, write it with conviction since you know you are right.

Answer (score 3):

You use `sh`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

But in your entrypoint file you use `bash`:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

You have to choose